# PlayFramework Websocket HTTP Status

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.2

I am playing around with WebSockets in PlayFramework 2.2. I would like to do some checks on the initial request and possibly return an appropriate HTTP status. In principle it would look like something like this, asked in [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/XLMWQsD4y9U):

```
def ws(username: String) = {
    if (username == "asoliman")
      Action { request =>
        Forbidden("Soliman is not allowed here")
      }
    else
      WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
        val in = Iteratee.foreach[String]( s => println("got: " + s)).mapDone(_ => println("Disconnected"))
        val out = Enumerator[String]("Ahmed", "Mohamed", "Ibrahim").andThen(Enumerator.enumInput(Input.EOF))
        (in, out)
      }
  }
```

As noted, this is not possible as the WebSocket's `using` and `async` need to return a `Tuple2[Iteratee, Enumerator]`.

Is there a recommended approach to this?
Or, is there a way to send [Websocket's Status Codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 7 October 2015:**

In newer PlayFramework versions, it is possible to reject a connection and therefore return, say, a Forbidden status. Check the documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWebSockets

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Answer is, it is not possible at the moment with PlayFramework 2.2. Regular HTTP statuses are not viable as the response needs to be a WebSocket (via using/async), and WebSocket statuses are not implemented. I filed an issue about it in their repo, we need to wait for future releases - or contribute to make it happen :-)

Comment: Are the websocket status codes implemented in "PlayFramework 2.3 or PlayFramework 2.4"? How Do I return response code in the web socket response?

Comment: I don't know if that's what you are looking for, but there is a way to reject websocket connection when using them together with actors: see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWebSockets